# Thymeleaf encoding issue

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf 3.0.3 with Spring Boot 1.5.1 and STS Bundle 3.8.1. My Hungarian non-ASCII characters are not shown properly.
I have the following configuration in the application.properties file:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=utf-8
```

These are anyway the defaults but I wanted to be sure that my Thymeleaf is configured properly.

My web page charset is also utf-8 and my text editor in Eclipse as well. So how can it happen that I see "�r�l�k, hogy �jra itt vagy Roland" instead of the expected: "Örülök, hogy újra itt vagy Roland"?

Comment: Do you have solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set encoding in the viewResolver

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver  thymeleafViewResolver(){
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I have found solution, that workerd for me:

You need to save the file as Encode in UTF-8 without BOM. It works for me. 
Steps: 
1. Edit the file in notepad++ and have a copy of these content in one more file. 
2. Go to menu Encoding and choose Encode in UTF-8 without BOM. 
3. If your file shows some char like xE9 etc., then copy original content to your file and save. 
4. Close and re-open the file and check the encoding remains same as "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". 
 If encoding default to Encode in AnsII that means you had few chars which are like "xE9" and your file didn't saved as Encode in UTF-8 without BOM. 
5. If encode remains "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". 
6. Run your application and you could able to see the translated content.

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF-8-encoding-problem-using-messages-properties-in-Spring-Boot-with-Thymeleaf-td4030339.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant, I experienced the same issue of not being able to display accented characters properly on my thymeleaf template. Example: Je vais � l'�cole.

This is what worked for me; in the `application.yml` file, add the following:

```
spring:
  messages:
    encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Result:
Je vais **à** l'**é**cole