# Thymeleaf Unexpected encoding

Tags: java, html, unicode, encoding, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf to have an html output file, as input I am using some java objects.

Just before using the thymeleaf objects, the debugger, is showing a correct encoding of "è" and "à" characters.

Please note that I already follwed the suggested actions described here: [Thymeleaf encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874927/thymeleaf-encoding-issue)

Do you have any Idea on what could I do?

As follows a portion of my Java code, my `template.html` and the `resultHTML`:

Java Code:

```java
TemplateEngine templateEngine = null;
templateEngine = initializeTemplateEngine();
Context context = new Context();context.setVariable("authDescriptions", 
    operationSummary.getAuthDescriptions());
String htmlOutput = templateEngine.process("template.html", context);

public static TemplateEngine initializeTemplateEngine() {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    return templateEngine;
}
```

templateHTML:

```html
<ul th:if="${authDescriptions != null and authDescriptions.size() > 0}">
    <li th:each="counter1 : ${#numbers.sequence(0, authDescriptions.size() - 1)}">
        <span th:data-lbl="${dataLableAuthList[counter1]}" th:text="${authDescriptions[counter1]}">
         </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

ResultHTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span data-lbl="settlement_v1_0_calculation_detail_list_AUTHDESC_2">Un API Key � una stringa di caratteri univoca utilizzata per autenticare e autorizzare le richieste di accesso e utilizzo di un&#39;API. Le API Keys sono spesso utilizzate per garantire che solo gli sviluppatori o le applicazioni autorizzate possano accedere e utilizzare le funzionalit� fornite da un&#39;API.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span data-lbl="settlement_v1_0_calculation_detail_list_AUTHDESC_3">Il JWT (JSON Web Token) � uno standard aperto (RFC 7519) che definisce un modo compatto e autonomo per trasmettere in modo sicuro le informazioni tra le parti come un oggetto JSON. I JWT sono spesso utilizzati come token di accesso in applicazioni web e API RESTful per trasportare informazioni di autenticazione e autorizzazione tra client e server. Sono autocontenuti e possono essere verificati facilmente dal server senza dover conservare alcuna informazione sullo stato del token.
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```